# Serialize base class only in ProtoBuf-net

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net

We have a base class and derived class. When we serialize a derived class, we want only the base class to be serialized. How can we achieve this in ProtoBuf-net.

Comment: I'd need more context: is the derived class "known" to protobuf-net, and you just want to ignore it? or is it unrelated implementation details that protobuf-net doesn't know about and will *never* know about? or...? maybe a code example?

Comment: protobuf-net v3 is getting a new option here; see edit

Answer (score 1):

Edit: new things in v3; the following now works:

```cs
[ProtoContract(IgnoreUnknownSubTypes = true)]
public class Foo {}
```

which does exactly what you want here.

---

Currently protobuf-net is not very forgiving of unexpected types, because it *really* wants to be able to round-trip your data. In the 3.0 codebase, this is currently restricted to:

- EF proxies, which it detects by the namespace `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies`
- NHibernate proxies, which it detects as anything that implements *by name* `NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy`, `NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.IProxy` or `NHibernate.Intercept.IFieldInterceptorAccessor`

I'm open to discussing new additions that could be added to relax this - it would probably need a little discussion, but: it should be possible. Simply adding a marker interface or attribute that the library recognizes as a "ignore this type" token seems pretty reasonable! In fact, as I think about it: it would seem that we could just use `[ProtoIgnore]` for this, by extending the `AttributeTargets` for `ProtoContractAttribute`, and adding a few lines to `DynamicStub.ResolveProxies`.

Right now, the following "works" (for limited values of "works"), with outputs:

```
Trying BaseType...
Success; got BaseType
Trying KnownSubTypeViaInclude...
Success; got KnownSubTypeViaInclude
Trying UnknownSubType...
Unexpected sub-type: UnknownSubType
Trying LooksLikeEFProxy...
Success; got BaseType
Trying LooksLikeNHibernateProxy...
Success; got BaseType
```

code:

```cs
using ProtoBuf;
using System;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // works, trivially
        Try<BaseType>();

        // works, processes sub-type
        Try<KnownSubTypeViaInclude>(); 

        // fails, unexpected
        Try<UnknownSubType>();

        // works, processes base type only
        Try<System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LooksLikeEFProxy>();
        Try<LooksLikeNHibernateProxy>();
    }
    static void Try<T>() where T : BaseType, new()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Trying {typeof(T).Name}...");
        try
        {
            var clone = Serializer.DeepClone<BaseType>(new T());
            Console.WriteLine($"Success; got {clone.GetType().Name}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(42, typeof(KnownSubTypeViaInclude))]
public class BaseType
{

}
public class KnownSubTypeViaInclude : BaseType { }
public class UnknownSubType : BaseType { }
public class LooksLikeNHibernateProxy : BaseType, NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy { }
namespace System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies
{
    public class LooksLikeEFProxy : BaseType { }
}
namespace NHibernate.Proxy // let's pretent to be NHibernate
{
    public interface INHibernateProxy { }
}
```

Comment: Our situation is, that we have a class A which is serializable with protobuf-net and a class B which inherits from A but does not have any protobuf-met annotations, so is not serializable. But we have the situation, that we do have a collection which contains objects of class A and B and this collection should be serialized. Obviously B can't be serialized but its base A can. So ideally we can tag class A somehow so that the serializer that should serialize class B knows, it must serialize as class A.
Maybe this is possible right now, but I don't know.

Comment: Any idea how to solve our situation with protobuf-net?

Comment: @ChristianBecker I explained all of this in the answer... a) what you're asking for isn't *directly* supported (and I explained why), b) I gave some hacks that *make it* work, and c) I speculated that I was open to *adding* more direct support but again - see "a" - it isn't there today; which part are you asking for clarification on, and exactly what would you like clarified